# How do I buy a penthouse?

Tags: the-sims-3, sims-3-late-night

My Sim wishes that they could live in a penthouse, because apparently they are not satisfied with the nicely decorated and roomy apartment they bought. I purchased all the available homes that were apartments in hopes that one would be a penthouse, but apparently none of them are, so I have a bunch of apartments around the city now. I have plenty of money, am a 2 star celeb, and own a large amount of real estate, though I don't have a "job" (I write and paint for a living so career is unemployed). Is there any requirements that I need to fulfill in order to purchase a penthouse? If  not, what can I do to purchase one?

Comment: this title out of context o.O

Comment: [penthouse](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Penthouse) : "Not to be confused with Apartment." What neighborhood are you in?

Comment: @Mazura Bridgeport

Comment: Are they available for purchase after you evict the Trills or the Jones's?

Comment: @Mazura I will check, not at home atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are 3 penthouses in Bridgeport: **Aria Trill's, The Jones's and the loft apartment near Waylon's haunt**. I've played in all of them and they are the only apartments where when you click on the mailbox you get "get mail from XXX penthouse". I believe it's because they are the one's with a terrace.
>   I remodeled the loft into a 3 bedroom apartment; but, **sometimes my sim still gets the wish to move into a penthouse. And she's living in the best penthouse in Bridgeport.** –[carl's](http://www.carls-sims-4-guide.com/forum/?topic=11698.0)

Comment: Well, evicting the Jones's and moving them to a different house, then buying their old house and moving in worked.